# Is there really a bugle trophy in Man of Steel?

Tags: reference, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

As per [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0770828/trivia?ref_=hm_trv_sm)

> In Perry White's office at the Daily Planet there is a bugle trophy on
>   top of the shelf.

This is surely a reference to the Marvel Comics newspaper office the Daily Bugle and I think I have also seen something like this in the film but with blurred memory.

So is there really a Bugle reference in the film or is it just miss-interpretation. 
If yes then, is it just an homage to Spider-Man or an approval of the Marvel universe's co-existence?

Comment: That linked page doesn't really 'confirm' anything.  It's an un-sourced wiki.  Anyone can put anything up there.

Comment: @Keen their is none other confirmation then this IMDb link, so for the moment i am deleting this question till i got any proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions here. Is there a bugle in the office and, if so, what does it symbolise.

So firstly, what is a bugle? As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugle)?:

> The bugle is one of the simplest brass instruments, having no valves
>   or other pitch-altering devices.

This is the picture from Wikipedia:

[image: Bugle]

So now we at least know what we're looking for.

To answer the first question, a quick speedrun of the film reveals that there **is** a bugle on Perry White's bookcase. I have included a screen below (taken at 43:21 in the film) with a box around the bugle:

[image: Picture of Bugle]

However, there appears to be no way to definitively answer the second question. I would argue it is *extremely likely* it is a homage to Marvel Comics, but I've found no interviews with either cast or film maker to corroborate this.

I believe it's a reference to Spiderman but, for now, I think it's largely a case of decide for yourself what you think it symbolises (if anything).

Comment: It SHOULD be on Lois' desk... 'cuz that woman loves to toot her own horn.